# Process finished with exit code 139 after updating from python 2.7.6 64 bit to 2.7.10 32 bit

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, python-imaging-library, pycharm

I have a script that opens images in a `Tkinter frame` with `PIL/pillow.` It was working fine yesterday when i was running `python 2.7.6 64 bit`, but in order to use `Pygame` later did i update to `python 2.7.10 32 bit` (pygame only runs on 32 bit). When running the same script today do i get Process finished with exit code 139, which i believe means `Invalid memory access`. If i run the script without running the function that includes pil.image will the script be executed normally. Anyone know how to adress this problem? I am running `OS x 10.10 Yosemite` and use `Pycharm`.

Comment: Well, you run into a segmentation violation (Signal 11, SEGV); the exit code is 128 + 11. It sounds like a bug in Python, since it should keep awys SEGVs from you and abort in a Python manner. (Of course it does not have to be core Python, it can be some library as well)

Comment: Might be a cache issue if the old pillow .pyc file is still around?